# How to set icon in a jtable while filling the table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to put an icon in a certain column depending on a condition but all get is the link of the image.

That's how initiated the table code:

```
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
                return Integer.class;
            case 2:
                return ImageIcon.class;
            default:
                return Object.class;
        }
    }
};
```

And then I fill the table from my database depending on a condition (finished-not started yet - and in progress ) :

```
    model.addColumn("Phases");
    model.addColumn("Date de début estimée(aaaa/mm/jj)");
    model.addColumn("Date de début réelle(aaaa/mm/jj)");
    model.addColumn("Date de fin estimée(aaaa/mm/jj)");
    model.addColumn("Date de fin réelle(aaaa/mm/jj)");
    model.addColumn("Status");
    model.addColumn("Tendance");

    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> last_name = new ArrayList<String>();

    String status = null;
    String tendance = null;
    byte[] Image = null;

   // ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\badr\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\UPLINE_GROUP\\src\\upline_group\\Ok-48.png");

    Date estimated_end_date = null;
    Date real_end_date = null;

    try {
        String sql = "select * from task WHERE id_project='" + id_project1 + "' ORDER BY nom_task ASC";
        PST = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        RS = PST.executeQuery();

        while (RS.next()) {
            try {
                String sql2 = "select * from image ";
                PST2 = conn2.prepareStatement(sql2);
                RS2 = PST2.executeQuery();

                while (RS2.next()) {

                    if (RS.getString("real_start_date") == null && RS.getString("real_end_date") == null) {
                        status = "0(Non Démarrée)";
                        //tendance = "0(Non Démarrée)";
                        Image = RS2.getBytes("non");
                    }
                    if (RS.getString("real_start_date") != null && RS.getString("real_end_date") == null) {
                        status = "1(en cours)";
                       // tendance = "1(en cours)";
                        Image = RS2.getBytes("cours");
                    }
                    if (RS.getString("real_end_date") != null) {
                        status = "2(Terminé)";
                       // tendance = "2(Terminé)";
                        Image = RS2.getBytes("fini");
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }

            estimated_end_date = RS.getDate("estimated_end_date");
            real_end_date = RS.getDate("real_end_date");
            model.addRow(new Object[]{RS.getString("nom_task"), RS.getDate("estimated_start_date"), RS.getDate("real_start_date"), estimated_end_date, real_end_date, status,Image});

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    jTable1.setModel(model);
```

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but all get is the link of the image :

Then that means you are storing text in that column.

You have a couple of problems that I can see:

You code is attempting to read an Image, but you need to store an `ImageIcon` in the `TableModel`. So you need to change your `addRow(...)` statement to use:

```
addRow(..., new ImageIcon(image));
```

So you add each value in the order you want them displayed in the table.

When you fix the above statement it looks like the Icon will be the 6th parameter of the `addRow(...)` statement. However, according to your `getColumnClass(...)` method the Icon is in the 2 column. Doesn't this seem strange to you?

Comment: thank you i don't know how i missed that ! it's working now !